# Cannot set property 'defaultAccount' of undefined

Tags: metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am trying to run a DApp with metamask enabled , but this error surfaces .

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My TOKEN</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./abi.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var MyToken;
    var Web3;  
      $(document).ready(function(){

      window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
        // Modern dapp browsers...
        if (window.ethereum) {
            window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
            try {
                // Request account access if needed
                await ethereum.enable();
                // Acccounts now exposed
                web3.eth.sendTransaction({from : web3.eth.defaultAccount});
            } catch (error) {
                // User denied account access...
            }
        }
        // Legacy dapp browsers...
        else if (window.web3) {
            window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
            // Acccounts always exposed
            web3.eth.sendTransaction({from : web3.eth.defaultAccount});
        }
        // Non-dapp browsers...
        else {
            console.log('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!');
        }
      });
      Web3.eth.defaultAccount = "0xCc525f550792D2c8154077B7F4a261dd024638C9";
          const address = '0x44e38857745536fC9d17dE71974512a250f9DF9b';
        MyToken = new Web3.eth.Contract(abi, address );
      });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @goodvibration - Need your expert advise.

Comment: You have `web3.eth.defaultAccount` in 2 places and `Web3.eth.defaultAccount` in 1 other place! And that's just to begin with. It seems pretty odd that you are setting this field that way. It's not gonna unlock this account on the node that your `web3` object is communicating with (which is what you need to ensure, in order to be able to execute `web3.eth.sendTransaction` with this account).

Comment: @goodvibration - Thanks , Now, if I delete 'Web3.eth.defaultAccount' , the new error is "Cannot read property 'Contract' of undefined". Please excuse me for my sketchy knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `web3.eth.defaultAccount` got deprecated in the new dapp browsers. This is how you can get current account now:

```
async function getAccounts(callback) {
    var accounts = await ethereum.enable();
    if (typeof(callback) == 'function') {
        callback(accounts);
    }
}

getAccounts(function(accounts) {
    if (accounts != undefined) {
        console.log(accounts[0], 'This is the current default account');
    }
});
```